# What's the name of this branched covering?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I've come across a double cover of $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C)$, ramified at $[1:1]$ and $[-1:1]$ in homogeneous coordinates, given as the quotient by the natural $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-action generated by $[x:y]\mapsto[y:x]$. This space is totally natural and must have a name! For instance, it can be obtained as the space of all ratios $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$ of eigenvalues of non-nilpotent $2\times2$ complex matrices (which is the case I'm interested in).

In the litterature the notion of "reduced symmetric product" sometimes arises as $M\times M\setminus\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. This is somehow related, but in the case I'm confronted to I want to keep the branch-point (corresponding to $\Delta\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ in the case $M:=\mathbb C$, before projectivization). Also I feel the context is not completely the same.

My question: how should I call/write $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C)~/~\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? Is there a standard denomination? Notation?

**Edit**: as Noam D. Elkies very rightly mentions in a comment, the quotient is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C)$, *via* the explicit parameterization $[x^2+y^2:xy]$. It doesn't settle the question of whether this particular perception of the projective line has a particular name, though. But maybe this is not interesting.

Comment: You could just call it ${\bf P}^1({\bf C})$ because it's a genus-zero Riemann surface; an explicit coordinate is $(x^2+y^2 : xy)$.

Comment: Hi @Balarka, is that true? For example, you can exhibit any Riemann surface as a branched double cover of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ (to exhibit this geometrically, put a skewer symmetrically through the surface and let $\mathbb{Z}/2$ act as rotation by 180 degrees about the skewer).

Comment: @AmiteshDatta, indeed, hyperelliptic curves $y^2=f(x)$ with polynomial $f$ are branched double covers, and can have any genus, so, as you hint, it is certainly not true that any branched double cover of $\mathbb P^1$ is again $\mathbb P^1$. :)

Comment: Dear @paul, thank you for your comment! :) I guess in that case one can also state that the genus of the surface will be the ceiling of $\frac{\text{deg}(f)-2}{2}$.

Comment: Note too that **Loïc Teyssier**'s double cover has two branch points (as expected by Riemann-Hurwitz): the involution $(x:y) \leftrightarrow (y:x)$ fixes not just $(1:1)$ but also $(-1:1)$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes indeed, thank you for your valuable input. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Indeed, I was being silly. There are lots of quadratic extensions of $\Bbb C(z)$, for one. I'll just delete the comment.

Comment: Viewed as a $2$ dimensional orbifold, I think what you have is the *spindle* $S^2(2,2)$. See p.13 of these slides, for example: http://www-sop.inria.fr/geometrica/collaborations/OrbiCG/slides_JoanPorti.pdf

Comment: I don't know of a name for this one, but a similar one is given by the quotient of an elliptic curve by the action of $\pm 1$ which yields a branched cover with four ramification points. This is called the *Pillowcase orbifold*.